# cy.setCookies() with domain option results in error

Tags: cypress

This works fine

```js
    beforeEach(function() {
      cy.setCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue');
    });
```

But this

```js
    beforeEach(function() {
          cy.setCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', {
            domain: 'http://example.com'
          });
        });
```

results in

```js
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Any hints?

Cypress package version: 3.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain option expects what it implies, a domain, so without the protocol.

```js
     cy.setCookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue', {
            domain: 'example.com'
          });
```